# Get quantity of missed elements from an array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve the task, get quantity of missed elements from an array. For example, if given an array [1,3,6], the quantity of missed elements is 3 (2,4,5). But somewhere code goes wrong and system doesn't accept the code.
I tried some methods, but unfortunately they are useless.

```
function arr(x){
 let y = [];
 for (let i = x[0]; i <= x[x.length-1]; i++){
    y.push(i);
 }
 return y.length-x.length;
}
let m = arr([1,2,3,4,5,6]);
console.log(m);
```

Or...

```
function arr(x){
    let y = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        for (let j = 0; j < i; j++){
            if (x[i] == x[j]){
                x.splice(i,1);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(x);
    for (let i = x[0]; i <= x[x.length-1]; i++){
        y.push(i);
    }
    console.log(y);
    return y.length-x.length;
}
let l = arr([1,3,2,4,9]);
console.log(l);
```

I also tried to sort array, but there are no changes

Comment: If you assume that the elements in your given array are in ascending order you can check the last element and make that your desired array length(so as to decide what and how many elements are missing).  That way you can be programmatic in the entire approach.  From there you should be able to use that value as the break point in your for loop and just push [i] to your new array if it doesn't match any index of the given array.

Comment: You might want to step away from the code for a minute. How would you preform this task by hand using pencil and paper. Think through the steps you need to solve the problem. Then write these steps down **in words**. When you have the steps written down clearly, then you can translate them into code (or modify your existing code to fit those steps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in following steps:

- Remove the duplicate elements from array.
- Get the range of array by subtracting first value from last.
- Subtract the range from the length of array.

**Note**: I am considering array is sorted.

```js
function missed(arr){
  arr = [...new Set(arr)];
  return arr[arr.length - 1] - arr[0] - arr.length + 1
}

console.log(missed([1,3,6]))
```

If you need to use this on a unsorted array. Then use `Math.max()` and `Math.min()`.

```js
function missed(arr){
  arr = [...new Set(arr)];
  let max = Math.max(...arr);
  let min = Math.min(...arr);
  return max - min - arr.length + 1
}

console.log(missed([1,3,6]))
console.log(missed([6,1,3]))
```

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, you don't really need a for loop. I think you can calculate the nr by checking the maximum number, the minimum number and the length of the array.

Would this also work for you?

```js
const source = [1,3,6];

/**
 * @method nrOfMissedItems
 * @param {Array<Number>} an array containing only numbers
 * @returns -Infinity when the parameter arr is null or undefined, otherwise number of non-mentioned numbers, ie [5,5] returns 0, [1,1,1,3] returns 1
 * When the array contains non-numbers it will return NaN
 */
function nrOfMissedItems( arr ) {
  const noDuplicates = [...new Set(arr)];
  const highestNumber = Math.max( ...noDuplicates );
  const lowestNumber = Math.min( ...noDuplicates );
  return highestNumber - lowestNumber - noDuplicates.length + 1;
}

console.log( nrOfMissedItems( source ) );         // 3
console.log( nrOfMissedItems( [1] ) );            // 0
console.log( nrOfMissedItems( [0,1,4] ) );        // 2
console.log( nrOfMissedItems( [5,3,1] ) );        // 2
console.log( nrOfMissedItems( [1,1,1,1,5] ) );    // 3
console.log( nrOfMissedItems( null ) );           // -Infinity
console.log( nrOfMissedItems( undefined ) );      // -Infinity
console.log( nrOfMissedItems() );                 // -Infinity 
console.log( nrOfMissedItems( ['a','b', 1] ) );   // NaN
console.log( nrOfMissedItems( ['a', null, 1] ) ); // NaN
console.log( nrOfMissedItems( [undefined, 1] ) ); // NaN
```

Comment: Good answer.  This covers both duplicates *and* unsorted arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if optimization is a must, bust the easiest non-ES6 (for all browsers support) way I can think of is to sort the array and iterate through it logging the numbers that you expect but are missing. Something like this:

```js
var arr = [4,1,6,8];
arr.sort();
var miss = [];
var expect = arr[0]; // The starting number is the first element in the array I guess. Change to 1 if you want it to be 1

// Loop through the sorted array
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    while(arr[i] > expect++) { // keep looping while the current number is not the one expected, and increment the expected by one
        miss.push(expect-1); // If missed, record the missed number (which is the actual expected minus 1, as we already incremented it)
    }
}

console.log(miss);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like :

```js
function arr(x){
 let y = [];
  let start = Math.min(...x);
  let end = Math.max(...x);
 for (let i = start; i <= end; i++){
    y.push(i);
 }
 return y.length-x.length;
}

let m = arr([1,3,6]);

console.log(m);
```